# Can you use "parenthesis" on Predicate operations

Tags: guava, predicate

I can't see any way to build a guava/Java `Predicate` that uses parenthesis to control logical order. Is there one?

Say I want to do something like:

```
Predicate <= mumble and (foo or baz)
```

A simple `Predicates.and` or a `Predicates.or` has no equivalent that says `"foo or baz" and with mumble`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

It just depends on how you construct it:

```
// (mumble and foo) or baz
Predicates.or(Predicates.and(mumble, foo), baz)

// mumble and (foo or baz)
Predicates.and(mumble, Predicates.or(foo, baz))
```

There's no real need for "parentheses" because it's unambiguous from the method calls themselves.

Comment: What about when using java.util.function ?

Comment: @DidierA.: I'd *expect* it to be exactly the same. I suggest you test it until you're either satisfied or have a specific question, at which point post it as a new SO question (after researching, of course).

Answer (score 0):

For those like me that were looking for this, but using Java 8 java.util.function Predicate instead:

```
// (mumble and foo) or baz
(mumble.and(foo)).or(baz)

// mumble and (foo or baz)
mumble.and(foo.or(baz))
```

Where mumble, foo and baz are all instances of java.util.function.Predicate